# Из списка товаров корзины отправляется только один товар

Tags: php, корзина

Есть такой код корзины. Проблема в том, что из всех товаров на email отправляется только последний товар в списке. Как исправить?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        foreach($_POST['quanity'] as $key => $val) {
            if($val==0) {
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }else{
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]['quanity']=$val;
            }
        }
    }

?>

<h1>View Cart</h1>

<a href="index.php?page=products">Go back to products page</a>


    <form method="post" name="tab" action="index.php?page=cart">
        <table>
            <tr> 
                <th>Name</th> 
                <th>Quanity</th> 
                <th>Price</th> 
                <th>Items Price</th> 
            </tr>

            <?php
                require("includes/connection.php");
                $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);
                $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(";
                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
                    $sql.=$id.",";
                }
                $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
                $query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
                $totalprice=0;
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
                    $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity']*$row['price']; 
                    $totalprice+=$subtotal;
            ?>

                <tr> 
                    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="quanity[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]" size="5" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity'] ?>" /></td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?>$</td> 
                    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity']*$row['price'] ?>$</td> 
                </tr> 

            <?php
                }
            ?>

            <tr> 
                <td colspan="4">Total Price: <?php echo $totalprice ?></td> 
            </tr> 
        </table>

        <br/>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Update Cart</button> 

        <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="Укажите ФИО">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Укажите e-mail">
        <button type="submit" name="order">Отправить</button>
    </form>


<?php
    require("includes/connection.php");
    $connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN(";
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) {
        $sql.=$id.",";
    }
    $sql=substr($sql, 0, -1).") ORDER BY name ASC";
    $query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $totalprice=0;

    if(isset($_POST['order'])){
        $headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= 'From: Your name <info@address.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){ 
            $subtotal=$_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity']*$row['price']; 
            $totalprice+=$subtotal;
            $content='
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>List of goods</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <tr> 
                    <td>' .$row["name"]. '</td> 
                    <td>' . $_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"]. '</td> 
                    <td>' .$row["price"]. '$</td> 
                    <td>' .$_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"]*$row["price"]. '$</td> 
                </tr> 
            </body>
            </html>
            ';
        }
            $message = $_POST['fio'].$content;
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
            $mail=mail($_POST['email'], 'My Subject', $message, $headers);
            if($mail){
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('OK');</script>";
            }
    }
?>




<br /> 
<p>To remove an item, set it's quanity to 0. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Your name <info@address.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    $content = '           
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>List of goods</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <table>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['id']]['quanity'] * $row['price'];
        $totalprice += $subtotal;
        $content .= '
                <tr> 
                    <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td> 
                    <td>' . $_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"] . '</td> 
                    <td>' . $row["price"] . '$</td> 
                    <td>' . $_SESSION["cart"][$row["id"]]["quanity"] * $row["price"] . '$</td> 
                </tr>
            ';
    }

    $content .= '
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>';

    $message = $_POST['fio'] . $content;
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
    $mail = mail($_POST['email'], 'My Subject', $message, $headers);
    if ($mail) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('OK');</script>";
    }
}
```

Вы поместили в цикл обявление переменной $content. Переменная должна обявляться до цикла а в теле дописыватся.

Comment: Аллилуйя) благодарю. Вы мне оч помогли)